# Sitecore: copy files at index update finish

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In our Sitecore project we have set a manual policy for indexing. We need to copy the indexes after the build to other servers. I know how we can copy the files from one server to another. So my question is:

How can I set a tool to run when the index rebuild is finished? Is this even possible?

We don't want do run the tool manually after each run.

Comment: Why are you copying index files to other servers? are these other CD servers?

Comment: we need the indexes on web servers

Comment: You should use RemoteRebuild strategy on your "web" indexes https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/search_and_indexing/index_update_strategies.
Basically this strategy will trigger rebuild index job on all of remote servers once the index is fully rebuilt on CM server.

I Definitely DON'T recommend you copy indexes between servers

Comment: ok I will look into it. Thank you

Comment: I don't believe copying the indexes to other servers will even work.  The index files will not be able to be queried for results.  You can use remote build or if the content delivery servers are running off of web db you can use publish strategy where the indexes rebuild after items are published.

Comment: The web server where I need to set the indexes are not connected as I remember to the Sitecore servers will the remote build work ?

Comment: @Radu As long as CD and CM servers are sharing the web database, the Remote Build strategy will work using EventQueue table, i advise you to use both OnPublishEndAsync and RemoteRebuild strategies on your "web" index, The config changes needs to be applied on your CD servers, This will ensure your index is synched all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call code when certain [events](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/all-about-events-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) have started or finished. 
In your case, one option is for you to hook into the `indexing:end` handler to start an `xcopy` command for instance - or call your tool programmatically from there.

Is there a reason why you can't keep the indexes up-to-date on the servers themselves?

Comment: thank you, I think this will work. I've also found some info here: http://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/02/sitecore-7-new-events.aspx

Comment: I dod have a question about indexing:end somehow seems that the sitecore do not catch the indexing:end. I've tried with item:locked and it worked. Does not matter what index I am rebuilding core/web or master the indexing:end should be raised right?